# Office Add-in: Cannot clean Word document after inserting ooxml (Office Online, works on Desktop)

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

Trying to replace the contents of a Word document after inserting it the first time. When I run this code:

```
Word.run(async context => {
  let range = context.document.body.getRange();
  let myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
  myContentControl.clear();
  myContentControl.insertOoxml(ooxml, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
  myContentControl.cannotEdit = false;
  myContentControl.cannotDelete = false;
  context.load(myContentControl, "id");
  await context.sync();
});
```

I get this error:

> **NotAllowed**
>   The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the `OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo` for more information.

If I use text and then run this code it gets inserted fine.

Could this be my `ooxml`?

Comment: What is the value of `OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo`? Also, can you provide a sample of the `ooxml` you are inserting?

Comment: Is your add-in allowed to write in the document? I believe you can specify this in the manifest.

Comment: Can you provide your original ooxml string that works on desktop but not online? this will help us locate the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the OOXML or the value of `OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo`, it is difficult to know where the problem is.

That said, you're doing a lot of unnecessary steps here:

```js
Word.run(async context => {
  let range = context.document.body.getRange();

  // Why insert a content control?
  let myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();

  // Since you just inserted this, there nothing to clear
  myContentControl.clear();

  // Similar, since this is new (and cleared) why "replace"
  myContentControl.insertOoxml(ooxml, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

  // Already the default value
  myContentControl.cannotEdit = false;
  myContentControl.cannotDelete = false;

  // Why load this when you're not doing anything
  // with the value you're loaded
  context.load(myContentControl, "id");

  // Little known tip/trick:
  // You don't need to sync here, Word.run() will automatically 
  // process anything in the queue when it completes
  await context.sync();
});
```

Before trying to diagnose if this is your OOXML string, I would start by first reducing the number of unneeded calls your making:

```js
Word.run(async context => {
  let range = context.document.body.getRange();
  range.insertOoxml('Your OOXML', 'Replace');
});
```

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because this code is indeed much simpler. The problem was the ooxml. We found that while trying to edit so that we could post a sample publicly. Couldnt put my finger on what the issue was but will provide a bit more info here on Monday. Thanks for the quick answer btw!